# bootstrap glyph icons is not compatibility in firefox and IE, but it is working in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have checked my reference also...

suggest me one answer how to compatibility the glyph icons in firefox and IE also.

When i am using small images in the place of glyphicons, it is working properly.

Comment: As part of the bootstrap templates they should be available and compatible with firefox and IE as stated here http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using some other plugin? [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) should work for you, and I'm sure it does work in Firefox and IE (I'm using it in one project now)

Comment: By using Font Awesome also i am facing same problem.

Comment: Can you post your code somwhere? I just can't believe both glyph-icons and font-awesome fail to work.

Comment: <span class="input-group-addon"><span
           class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>

Comment: <span class="input-group-addon"><i
           class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>

Comment: i am able to change glyph icons by using font awesome also...  but it is only visible in chrome only. Same problem i am facing when i am using FF or IE

Comment: Well... I meant putting your code on some page like jsFiddle. From what I see in your comments I can't say what's wrong.